# Exclude most recent articles of a certain category, from another category's query (WP)

Tags: php, wordpress

here's my current query:

```
query_posts('category_name=featured-posts&order=desc&showposts=5');
```

Now, what I want to do is to look for a category labeled 'tiled-posts', check if my first three posts in this query appear as 'tiled-posts' and are the three most recent posts in that category (tiled-posts), if they are, I want to exclude them from this query.

in summary, I have a slider that shows 3 tiled-posts and I want those to be excluded from this query.

Please tell me if this is unclear and I will try to clarify a bit more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this personally but I think there's an offset option. Try this:

```
query_posts('category_name=tiled-posts&order=desc&showposts=5&offset=3');
```

This should exclude the 3 most recent posts from the query.

Comment: The problem is that the excluded posts need to be matched for a second category, the direction I'm going in is to query that second category, put the first three ids in an array, then exclude them; but I haven't yet gotten a working/showable example.

Comment: Okay, so you have two queries, for featured-posts and tiled-posts, and you want the three most recent tiled-posts excluded from featured-posts, is that correct?

Comment: Ah, I was misinterpreting it then, sorry. It seems to me that it would be easier to use two loops querying the same category, with `showposts=3` displaying the three most recent tiles and `showposts=5&offset=3` displaying the next five posts in a different place. I know that's not the answer you're looking for though - if I think of a way to do what you're asking I'll let you know!

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, I will post the solution I came to after I test it thoroughly. What I did is query tiles, and put the IDs of the posts in an array, then I used posts__not_in to exclude them from the next query. So far it looks to be working correctly.